# Angular - custom directive for preventing default behavior not working

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to write a directive for preventing the default behavior. Here's the code

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[app-event-blocker]',
})
export class EventBlockerDirective {
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  public handleEvent(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Then i import it in shared module, declare it, and export

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { EventBlockerDirective } from './directives/event-blocker.directive';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ModalComponent,
    EventBlockerDirective,
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [
    EventBlockerDirective,
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

And then import it in Video module, where i use it

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule],
})
export class VideoModule {}
```

Then i use it in Video component

```
<div app-event-blocker>
  <h5>Drop your file here (mp4 only!)</h5>
</div>
```

But when i drop file in the box, it opens it in browser instead of not doing anything. When i add event handlers and prevent default behavior there it works, but i want to do it with directive.
I'd appreciate if you could help me understand what is wrong with it.
Full code can be found in the github [repo](https://github.com/SymphonyNineth/clips)

Comment: But your `UploadComponent` doesn't belong to `VideoModule` and declared in `AppModule`. So I imported `SharedModule` in `AppModule` and it works.

Comment: Hi. I declared UploadComponent in VideoModule and everything worked. Thank you very much for your help.
Can you write this as an answer, so i mark it as a solution?

Comment: Okay. Btw, you can use _the right IDE_ that will help you with such moments ;)

Comment: @Eugene Which IDE is right?)

Comment: Webstorm for me, but I'm sure there is a plugin for VSCode that can do this too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Directive that provides attribute app-event-blocker is out of the current Angular module's scope`

`UploadComponent` doesn't belong to `VideoModule` and declared in `AppModule`.
So you should import `SharedModule` in `AppModule`.